# Why appsearch-validation-tool gives error for my domain hosted in AWS EC2 with apache2 and php7?

Tags: ios, deep-linking, apache2.4, ios-universal-links, apple-app-site-associate

I have uploaded the **apple-app-site-association** file in the .well-known directory [Here you can check the file](https://thestories.in/.well-known/apple-app-site-association) and used **Files "apple-app-site-association"
 ForceType 'application/json'
Files(Removed angle brackets)** to force **content-type -> application/json**. I have checked the response in postman the response is perfect and got the content-type-> application/json in header. Tried to use **curl -I URL** got the correct response and content-type-> application/json. Verified with [Branch validator](https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/#resultsbox) got everything green.

All the things look perfectly fine but still, my domain can't pass in [Apple App Search API Validation Tool](https://search.developer.apple.com/appsearch-validation-tool), getting error **Action required
Could not extract required information for Universal Links. Learn how to implement the recommended Universal Links**. I have verified everything so many times even I forgot to count how many yet can't figure out what did I miss.

Can anyone please give me some idea what did I miss or how can I check what is wrong in my setup. Please let me know if I can provide any more details about my server or anything relevant to this error.
Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: How your file looks like? What is the path you store your file?

Comment: I have added the link in my question you can check it by clicking the link named "Here you can check the file".